# How to name a newer version of command, which is not fully compatible with old version

Tags: package-management, deployment

I have two versions of the same command. The newer version is not fully backward compatible with the old version. Should I add version number to the command name in this case like so

```
/usr/bin/foo
/usr/bin/foo-2
```

Where foo-2 is the new version (2.0), or is there some other deployment strategy? This alternative would break if the old version becomes obsolte, and foo now actually is foo-2. How to deal with that.

Comment: One sometimes sees "ng" for "new generation", but rarely or never for the actual binaries of programs. Or `awk` is sometimes named `gawk`, though it's backward-compatible. Or you see version numbers, like in Python. In short, there is no standard.

Comment: On my system:
$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5

So adding the version number to the binary may be a working idea.